# MS Office solo lectura samba fedora

Tags: linux, samba, fedora, microsoft-office

tengo montado el servicio samba en fedora 24 como MIEMBRO DEL DOMINIO pues WINDOWS SERVER MANEJA LA RED, estoy compartiendo unos directorios los cuales ya son visibles en la red, es decir hasta el momento parece que samba trabaja bien, pero el problema esta con los archivos word o excel ppt etc pues en primera instancia abren solo de lectura, le cambio las propiedades con chmod 777 al los archivos y despues de eso los puedo editar y cuando guardo cierro y vuelvo a abrir el archivo me sale de nuevo solo de lectura, espero puedan ayudarme, dejo la configuracion de samba

quiero hacer enfasis en que solo pasa con ese tipo de archivos pues si comparto un bloc de notas se puede editar guardar abrir normalmente

Comment: No se ve la configuración de Samba, ¿puedes añadirla?